# What does the pattern {sp} in c++ regex / flex++ mean?

Tags: c++, regex, flex-lexer

What does {SP} mean in regex? for example what would this match?

(word1{SP}?word2{SP}{AAA})

I am not quite sure what it could mean. I thought it was a keyword, but now I think it might be something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's a [definition expansion](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Definitions-Section.html). Look for `SP` in the definitions section of your flex file.